# Array sorts sorts into descending instead of ascending

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

This program I wrote to sort an array into ascending order sorts it into descending and I don't understand why. Any help appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a[20] = { 21, 31, 1, 5, 3, 7, 87, 324, 21, 990, 34, 33, 21, 123, 54, 45,
            66, 76, 23, 44 }, t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            if (a[i] < a[j]) {
                t = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = t;
                }

        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << "\t";
    }
}
```

Comment: change your inner loop; or read array properly and how to use the inner or outer loop to compare the value.

Comment: It didn't when I tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the condition you wrote

```
if (a[i] < a[j])
```

so if the previous element is smaller than the farther element it gets swapped

Answer (score 0):

Change `if (a[i] < a[j])  to if (a[i] > a[j])`
For sorting in ascending order you want to swap elements when previous element is greater than the next element.
This animation will help you to understand the working of bubble sort http://cathyatseneca.github.io/DSAnim/web/bubble.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make any change, If you start your inner loop from (i+1)th position.
Replace the second code with following snippet:

```
for (int j = i+1; j < 20; j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in your **innerloop j = i+1;**

```
 int a[20] = { 21, 31, 1, 5, 3, 7, 87, 324, 21, 990, 34, 33, 21, 123, 54, 45,
                        66, 76, 23, 44 }, t;
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                    for (int j = i+1; j < 20; j++) { // not j=0, please use use **j=i+1;**
                        if (a[i] < a[j]) {
                            t = a[i];
                            a[i] = a[j];
                            a[j] = t;
                            }

                    }
                }
```